# Does passing value by pointer instead of value slow the programs ?

Tags: c

An experienced programer claims that passing values by pointer can slow the program or at least the compiler. Is that true ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=w7ay7QXmo_o#t=288

Comment: What??  It depends on what the pointer is pointing to - what it represents.  Passing or signalling a 10MB buffer by value would not exactly speed up a program.

Comment: I highly doubt passing by pointer would slow the program; quite the opposite, I'd suspect, because passing by value would require copying the value beforehand, then deleting the copy afterwards.  As for the compiler, I doubt noticeably.  If I thought I was an "expert programmer" I would make this an answer.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to watch the video, but I'm feeling bad enough as it is from the celebrations.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "slows the compiler" is a valid consideration when deciding how to implement.

Comment: @DanFarrell But copying may be faster that indirection.

Comment: The guy in the video talks for about 5 minutes on the rationale for this (the small function in question will probably be inlined, escape analysis, pointer aliasing, etc) and points out that this is only for small structures. If "is passing a struct by value faster than passing a pointer" is the only thing you got out of this, you should watch it a few more times and research more into the terms you didn't understand.

Comment: The `it depends` answer is unhelpful and not constructive. Why even comment?

Answer (score 3):

I watched the given segment of the video.

Situation:
A guy has a small third-party struct and passes it by value.

Why is it good:
1. Small struct doesn't take so much space to slow down the parameter passing through stack and you can (theoretically) achieve better memory/cache usage since you don't use the pointer to access memory. It's possible that compiler/optimizer couldn't do this for you as the guy mentions.
2. It is a third-party struct, it is not very probable that its size will change during the development of the program.
3. There is a difference in what the function signature is saying about its access/ownership with regard to the struct when it takes const pointer vs non-const pointer vs value, ...

What is questionable:
1. The guy doesn't really explain in-depth what is going on and why he did this optimization. Why to do it and speak about it at all then?
2. I don't see how this would slow down a compiler/optimizer in any way, but I'm not any expert on this matter.

Why this shouldn't be a general programming rule:
1. If you're not using a third-party struct, it is quite probable that your struct will change during the development process and you will either have inefficient code or alot to rewrite. Or probably the compiler will do the job for you and then there's no point of starting with it in the first place.
2. In development process where you are creating a new code, only thing you should think about performance-wise is the efficiency of the core algorithms and datastructures. If you write terrible sort algorithm, you won't help it by passing a struct by a value. As mentioned in comments, it depends on the consequences. I doubt that anyone can really foresee that something as marginal (performance-wise) as passing by value vs passing by pointer, when it comes to small structs, makes significant performance impact. Making such decision should be based on either knowing the consequences very well (ideally having solved this exact issue earlier) or having a profiler report that states that there is a performance problem with this.

Taking that into account, then a function that updates the game(?) window, that is run 60 or possibly even 120 times per second, is to be assumed the core of the program and should be optimized as much as possible. And it seems that the guy was working on it and found that he gets better results by passing the struct by value instead of passing by pointer.